# pass variables from HTML Form to php class instance

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

this the problem , when i execute the form it send nothing to database , if i insert directly : 4product = new produit(0) it works , so i cant send the variable via the form to instance if it is doable.

```html
<div class="bs-example">
    <h1>Ajouter un produit</h1>
    
    <form action="../produit_insert_form.php" method="POST"  class="form-horizontal" >
        

         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="code_p">ID de produit:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
               <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="code_p"  placeholder="ID">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="design">Designation:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9"> 
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="design"   placeholder="Designation">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="type">TYPE:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="type"   placeholder="TYPE">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="qte">QTE:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qte"  placeholder="QTE">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="prix">PRIX:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
               <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="prix" placeholder="PRIX">
            </div>
        </div>
   
            
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ajouter">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```html
require_once'produit.php';



 $code_p = isset($_POST['code_p']);

 $design =isset($_POST['design']);

 $type = isset($_POST['type']);

 $qte = isset($_POST['qte']);

  $prix = isset($_POST['prix']);


 
 
 $product = new produit($code_p) ; //create instance (Object) - classe Produit - with __construct()
     
 
 $product->setAttributs($design,$type,$qte,$prix);

  

 
  $product->write();
```

```html
class Produit {
  private $code_p = '';
  private $design;
  private $type;
  private $qte;
  private $prix;
  
  public function __construct($id){
   require_once 'connectdb.php';

   $this->code_p = $id; 
   if ($id > 0){
    $query = "select * from produits where code_p = '$this->code_p'";
    $result = cmySQL::executQuery($query);
    while($Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
       {
           $this->design = $Row['design'];
           $this->type = $Row['type'];
           $this->qte = $Row['qte'];
           $this->prix = $Row['prix'];
          }
   }
  }

  public function setAttributs($design, $type, $qte, $prix){
   $this->design = $design;
   $this->type = $type;
   $this->qte = $qte;
   $this->prix = $prix;
  }

  public function setCode_P($code_p){
   $this->code_p = $code_p;
  }

  public function getCode_P(){
   return $this->code_p;
  }

  public function setDesign($design){
   $this->design = $design;
  }

  public function getDesign(){
   return $this->design;
  }

 
        public function setType($type){

          $this->type=$type;

      }
       
       
          public function getType(){

       
               return $this->type;

  }


            public function  setQte($qte){

      $this->qte=$qte;
    }
 

        public function getQte(){

            return $this->qte;

       }




        public  function setPrix($prix){
        $this->prix=$prix;
        }
        
     public function getPrix(){

         return $this->prix;
       } 

    

    




 // function pour insertion des donnees dans la table produits //
 public function  write() 
 {
  require_once 'connectdb.php';

  if ($this->code_p == 0){
   $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO produits(code_p,design,type,prix,qte) VALUES('$this->code_p','$this->design','$this->type','$this->prix','$this->qte')";
  }
  else{
   $sqlQuery = "UPDATE produits SET `design` = '$this->design', `type` = '$this->type', `qte` = '$this->qte', `prix` = '$this->prix' WHERE code_p='$this->code_p'";
  }
  
    cmySQL::executQuery($sqlQuery);
 }

 public function delete(){
  require_once 'connectdb.php';
  $sqlQuery = "delete from produits where code_p='$this->code_p'";
  //die ($sqlQuery);
  cmySQL::executQuery($sqlQuery);
 }
```

Comment: `isset()` returns a boolean true/false. it will **NEVER** return the value submitted by the form - it'll just tell you if something was submitted.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should maybe consider to add more explanatory text about exactly what your problem is and not just paste all of your code. Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: really sorry , am new in stackoverflow , thank you for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chief problem is that you're assigning variables with the result of `isset()`, which is a boolean value (true/false), not the value of the POST variables. It should be this:

```
$code_p = $_POST['code_p'];

$design = $_POST['design'];

$type = $_POST['type'];

$qte = $_POST['qte'];

$prix = $_POST['prix'];
```

In addition to validating your data when received, you should also be doing something in your class `write()` method to prevent against injection attacks such as `mysqli_escape_string()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php) or, preferably,  prepared statements (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). What you have now is currently very insecure and susceptible to an injection attack.

Comment: when i  use  : $code_p = $_POST['code_p'] ;   i get : Notice: Undefined index: code_p

Comment: You need to give a `name` attribute to the `input` elements in your HTML, like `<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="code_p" id="code_p"  placeholder="ID">`

Comment: @khaledz You should also wrap everything in `produit_insert_form.php`, except for the `require_once`, with a `if (!empty($_POST)) { ... }` statement. Please let me know if these two comments help you.

Comment: it works ! , the problem is sloved , Chris thank you very much , and also tnx for all

Comment: @khaledz No problem! If you could mark my answer as the accepted answer, I'd really appreciate it. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your form with this

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <h1>Ajouter un produit</h1>

    <form action="../produit_insert_form.php" method="POST"  class="form-horizontal" >


         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="code_p">ID de produit:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
               <input type="text" name="code_p" class="form-control"  id="code_p"  placeholder="ID">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="design">Designation:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9"> 
               <input type="text" name="design" class="form-control" id="design"   placeholder="Designation">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="type">TYPE:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" name="type" class="form-control" id="type"   placeholder="TYPE">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="qte">QTE:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
               <input type="text" name="qte" class="form-control" id="qte"  placeholder="QTE">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="prix">PRIX:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
               <input type="text" name="prix" class="form-control"  id="prix" placeholder="PRIX">
            </div>
        </div>


        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ajouter">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Kindly, let me know if there is any issue.